# Recommended aplications for software development

Tags: git, svn, version-control, cvs

In a business context, which applications do you recomend for:

- [Version Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software)
- [Time Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_management)
- [Knowledge Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_base)

Compared with the possible solutions, what are their main advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For version control, I have been using Git for quite some time, and using Git with Github is very good for managing your code. Github also supports private repositories if you need that functionality. I've also used CVS and bazaar which work well for version control.

For time management I assume you mean for planning, calendars, etc. For a free solution, Google's Calendar has plenty of features for working with a team and making sure you stay on time.

As for a knowledge base, you could use a local mediawiki set up, relatively simple to set up and free.

I reccomend all of these from personal experience and from working in teams. Of course, there may be better paid alternatives but these have worked well together for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Version control is either Subversion, Mercurial, or Git.  The latter two are the most modern.

I'd recommend Fog Creek's FogBugz for time management.  It'll help with your estimating, too.

Don't have anything about knowledge management.  Try a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question is more suited for:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101916/recommended-aplications-for-software-development